# 08 f150 with vibration in the front driver side tire when turning left only.

Tags: ford, suspension

2 months ago I installed a 2 inch suspension lift and replaced upper control arms, tie rods and shocks. The tires were pretty bad and got worse quickly. Vibration and noise started shortly after.Mechanic said it was tires and I replaced them last week. Noise was better at first but already getting worse. any ideas??

Comment: Have you re torqued all the bolts since doing the work? Are your CV joints okay, if applicable? Have you had the tracking/alignment/camber checked by a shop with a laser?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on an 04 F150 Lariat. After many trips to Ford dealer. Came to find out clutches in limited slip diff were worn out. 4wd, always used 2wd. Replaced the clutches in rear end and had no more issues. I was told tires at first as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have a front wheel bearing/hub that is bad. With the steering wheel locked, safely raise the front wheel off the ground. Grab the tire and rock it back and forth while holding the tire at the left and right sides. Do it again while holding the tire at the top and bottom. There should be no percevible movement of the tire. Slowly rotate the tire to feel for any grinding or rumble in the bearing. Even if you do not feel anything unusual the bearing may only be vibrating while under load. The left front typically sees more load than the right front in 4x4 mode. Being 6 years old I would guess that the right front is also worn, just not as bad. Since you have a lift kit I assume you also have oversized tires. The extra weight and loads from the tires can cause premature bearing wear. They may not cause a failure they will just wear faster. On another note did you get an alignment after the lift kit was installed? Altering the suspension can change the alignment. You may want to check with an alignment shop that works on lifted trucks. Some times after the lift the vehicle requires alignment settings that are different from the stock setting.

Comment: 2 wheel drive truck.. noise started after lift but before larger tires. last alignment guys said was a waste because old tires were shot. going to bearing today but i replaced rotors maybe 6 moths ago and pretty sure bearing assembly was built in with rotor so they should be new. could i have not got the tie rod back in the proper position? tires "look" straight and it dosent pull

Answer (score 0):

Wheel Bearing seems logical dependent on Mileage, could also be brake caliper issue. is the truck 2 or 4WD.